# i have .xml file and i want search quickly by name title. i create button search and textbox for type the name. but always popup "item not found"

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    search()

End Sub

Private Sub search()
    Dim input As String = txtSearch.Text.Trim
    If input.Length = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
    xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("C:\Bison\POS\Memo\memo_index.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dv As DataView
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)

    dv = New DataView(ds.Tables(0))
    dv.Sort = "title"
    Dim dex As Integer = dv.Find("txtHeader.Text")

    If dex = -1 Then
        MsgBox("Item Not Found")
    Else
        MsgBox(dv(dex)("title").ToString() & " '" & input & "%' " & dv(dex)("file").ToString())
        '& dv(index)("Product_Price".txtSearch).ToString())
    End If
```

Sample XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet> 
  <Table> 
    <title>Memo - Best Customer Service Award (Hari B C ).</title>  
    <file>041115170756.pdf</file>  
    <creation>04/11/2015 5:07:56 PM</creation> 
  </Table>  
  <Table>..</Table> 
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <title>Memo - Best Customer Service Award (Hari B C ).</title>
    <file>041115170756.pdf</file>
    <creation>04/11/2015 5:07:56 PM</creation>
  </Table>
  <Table>..... .xml path

Comment: You can use [LINQ-to-XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to read value from XML. Which element do you want to read from that XML?

Comment: i want to search 'title' only from xml.

Comment: You're searching for a field value of `"txtHeader.Text"`, which does not exist in your XML. Why would you expect Find to locate the name of a TextBox property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use `txtSearch.Text` in method Find of DataView without "" like this :

`Dim dex As Integer = dv.Find(txtSearch.Text)`

the method Find of DataView, finds a row in the DataView by the specified sort key value, you must put a correct name title in search TextBox.

it work for me well, you can view my example below :

XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet> 
  <Table> 
    <title>Memo - Best Customer Service Award (Hari B C ).</title>
    <file>041115170756.pdf</file>  
    <creation>04/11/2015 5:07:56 PM</creation> 
  </Table>  
   <Table> 
    <title>Test</title>  
    <file>041115170756.pdf</file>  
    <creation>04/11/2015 5:07:56 PM</creation> 
  </Table>  
</NewDataSet>
```

Code :

```
Private Sub ButtonSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSearch.Click
    Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
    xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("C:\Bison\POS\Memo\memo_index.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dv As DataView
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
    dv = New DataView(ds.Tables(0))
    dv.Sort = "title"
    Dim dex As Integer = dv.Find(txtSearch.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
    If dex = -1 Then
        MsgBox("Item Not Found")
    Else
        MsgBox("Item Found")
    End If
End Sub
```

Test Result :

[image]

Comment: @rokayah I have change my answer, you can test it!

Comment: but i cannot use DataGridView, i use list view.. but, DataSource not member in ListView.

Comment: I use DataGridView just to set an example and that the method `dv.Find(txtSearch.Text)` work weel; you must put a correct name title in search TextBox, any characters or different fo check title!